# Storing binary null values in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, uuid

I'm dealing with a lot of UUIDs and I've been reading around the web that it's a good idea to

```
pack('H*',$uuid)
```

the strings before storing them in the database to save on storage, and then use

```
sprintf('insert .... values (%s,...)', $connection->quote($packed_uuid))
```

But the problem is sometimes whenever I get '00' in my UUID that converts to NULL character and fails to properly write to the database. Is there something that I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: it's php... you don't need sprintf unless you're formatting numbers.

Comment: You mean besides using string functions to be a query? Get with the times, use mysqli...

Comment: Notwithstanding the criticisms above, you might want to try sprintf('insert .... values ("%s",...)', $packed_uuid) ... momd the quotes

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to pack UUIDs - they are not very big, mostly random and the memory savings are quite small. Even if you deal with a million uuid it's not worth to compress them

Comment: wes: I would use PDO but i'm modifying an old existing code :(

Comment: Eugen Rieck: Tried that, but sometimes I'll get binary value of '"' which will again screw up the quotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I shouldn't be packing it when storing the values and let mysql pack it itself.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO uuid_demo SET id=0x1e8ef774581c102cbcfef1ab81872213, name="Kekoa";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

And selecting it:

```
mysql> SELECT hex(id), name FROM uuid_demo;
+----------------------------------+-------+
| hex(id)                          | name  |
+----------------------------------+-------+
| 1E8EF774581C102CBCFEF1AB81872213 | Kekoa | 
+----------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For more info visit [here](http://kekoav.com/posts/uuid-primary-key-mysql)